# How to authenticate pyspark streaming to secured sasl plain kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Im trying to Streaming from spark to secured kafka brokers (using SASL PLAINTEXT mechanism). 
im using Pyspark that using spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 version, and im using kafka broker version 0.10.2.

i get issue that when pyspark streaming to kafka doesn't return anything in output.

and my question is:

- How to authenticate properly from spark streaming to secured sasl plain kafka?
- Or does pyspark have support for authenticate to secured sasl plain kafka? im curious that pyspark is only supported by spark-streaming-kafka-0-8. since in that version, the initial support for spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 is kafka broker version 0.8.2, since kafka authentication is supported in version 0.9.

additional:

- I can publish and subscribe using console tools since i was set the acls for my user to the topic that i want to use.

Here's the detail that maybe can explain the issue.

additional parameter for enable sasl plain in server.properties for kafka broker

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
super.users=User:admin
```

here's also my kafka_jaas_server.conf

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin1!"
    user_admin="admin1!"
    user_aldys="admin1!";
};
```

i've also include my jaas config when start the kafka broker. via editing the kafka-server-start.sh in last line to:

```
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas_server.conf kafka.Kafka "$@"
```

Comment: back then, i can use pyspark streaming to kafka when kafka broker is only use default configuration that doesn't using any security mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think kafka0-8 supports sasl, from the documents it is pretty clear that only kafka0-10 has sasl capability and kafka0-10 does not supports Python.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html says SSL is not supported, which is not the same as SASL